# Puppet : How to loop to check the status of an exec command

Tags: puppet

In one of my Puppet manifests, I am running the exec command to run a job on a remote server and dump the output into a file. The file contents are in json and it contains a couple of fields. One field is the status, which decides whether the job is complete and another is the jobid, which provides the id of the job. If the status is complete, I use the jobid to query the server for more information. If the status is not complete, I need to keep looping until the job is complete.

I realize that exec has "try_sleep" but since I need to parse the json file after the exec, I don't believe I can use it.

How do I go about solving this one ?

As requested by Alex, adding the sequence below

```
Use exec command to execute some statement > /tmp/phase1.json

Parse /tmp/phase1.json and extract fields status and jobid

If field status is not complete, keep looping until it completes

If field status is complete, take the jobid and perform further processing
```

Comment: Can you update with the exact sequence of commands that you wish to execute with exec or multiple execs?

Comment: You can definitely do this, but it will be super hacky. You need to provide much more specific commands than what you provided in response to Alex's comment though.